# icon image doesn't follow size style on ios mobile devices

Tags: html, css, ios, responsive-design

I have 2 icon images that display ok on PC and android devices - proper size. But on iOS mobile devices, icons are smaller. I use Chrome to test web pages.

css:

```
 #info-icon, #info-icon-1 {
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      right: -60px;
      top: -10px;
    }
```

HTML

```
        <div id="info-icon">
          <button type="button" class="icon-btn" @click="openPopHelp">
            <img alt="" width="40" height="40" src="{% static 'images/help_icon.png' %}" />
          </button> 
        </div>
```

What to do to make icons be proper size 40x40 on ios devices?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#info-icon, #info-icon-1 {
      height: 40px!important;
      width: 40px!important;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      right: -60px;
      top: -10px;
    }
```

```
       <div id="info-icon">
          <button type="button" class="icon-btn" @click="openPopHelp">
            <img alt="" width="40px" height="40px" src="{% static 'images/help_icon.png' %}" />
          </button> 
        </div>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I found out what the problem was. I set styling on parent div not on img itself. For android and PC it works ok but for ios mobile devices you have to set style inside img tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I set style to images through parent div. It works for PC and android devices but ios mobile devices are much picky.
I changed:

```
 #info-icon, #info-icon-1 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  top: -10px;
}
.icon-img{
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

And in HTML:

```
           <div id="info-icon">
              <button type="button" class="icon-btn" @click="openPopHelp">
                <img alt="info icon" class="icon-img" width="35" height="35" src="{% static 'mifit/images/help_icon.png' %}" />
              </button> 
            </div>
```